# Use directory name to group tests rather than annotation for Maven SureFire

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I have TestNG tests that are grouped with the (groups = "unit") annotation as unit or integration and run using the following Maven config:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <groups>${test.group}</groups>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                    <include>**/Test*.java</include>
                    <include>**/When*.java</include>
                </includes>
                <argLine>${test.args.unit} -Xmx1024m</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I would like to separate test groups by directory structure instead of annotations and place the unit tests under a directory called unit.

So for example a unit tests in: src/test/java/foo/FooTests/MyFoo.java
I want to move it to: src/test/java/foo/unit/FooTests/MyFoo.java.
Then change the Maven config to pick up Java files under a unit subdir for unit tests.

I tried doing this by changing the plugin config to use the following include:

```
            <groups>${test.group}</groups>
            <includes>
                <include>**/unit/**/*Test.java</include>
                <include>**/unit/**/Test*.java</include>
                <include>**/unit/**/When*.java</include>
            </includes>
```

But that doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is that you should use a more up-to-date [maven-surefire-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/) (2.12.4) and furthermore dont use includes, cause maven-surefire-plugin has defaults for Unit tests. If you have integration tests better use [maven-failsafe-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin/) and name them appropriately. If you use TestNG in combination it sounds more like integration tests.

Comment: We are using both the surefire and the failsafe plugins. The first runs TestNG test classes with group "unit" and the second runs group "integration". I would like to stop using groups and use directories to separate test groups.

Comment: Better use a separte integration test module which contains only the integration tests is the best solution. Furthermore.

Answer (score 0):

If you name your Unit testes like '*Test' and your Integration Tests as '*IT' then the plugins will pick the right tests.